# unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.string' (combobox populate PictureBox)

Tags: c#

and sorry for the inconvenience. I hope you can help me! I have this code, which by selecting a combobox populates a series of textboxes. Now I would like to make sure to add, in addition to the textbox, also a picturebox, but I get the error as per the title. How can I proceed? Here is the code. Thanks everyone for the help.

```
// STRINGA CHE PERMETTE DALLA COMBOBOX VIA DI DETERMINARE IL REFERENTE
    private void cboVia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = constring;
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "SELECT Referenti.IDReferenti, Referenti.CognomeRF, Referenti.NomeRF, Referenti.ZonaRF, Referenti.LinkRF, Referenti.CodiceFotoRF, Referenti.TelefonoRF, Referenti.EmailRF, Referenti.ImageRF, Vie.Settore, Vie.Zona, Vie.Via FROM  Referenti FULL OUTER JOIN  Vie ON Referenti.ZonaRF = Vie.Zona where Via = '" + cboVia.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con2);
        SqlDataReader dbr;
        try
        {

            con2.Open();

            dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dbr.Read())
            {
                //string sID = (string)dbr["IDReferenti"].ToString();
                string CognomeReferente = (string)dbr["CognomeRF"]; // name is string value
                string NomeReferente = (string)dbr["NomeRF"];
                string ZonaReferente = (string)dbr["ZonaRF"];
                string EmailReferente = (string)dbr["EmailRF"];
                string CodiceFotoReferente = (string)dbr["CodiceFotoRF"];
                string imageRF = (string)dbr["ImageRF"];
                //txtID.Text = sID;
                txtCognomeReferente.Text = CognomeReferente;
                txtnomeReferente.Text = NomeReferente;
                txtEmailReferente.Text = EmailReferente;
                txtZona.Text = ZonaReferente;
                txtcodiceFotoReferente.Text = CodiceFotoReferente;
                // PICTUREBOX
                imageRFPictureBox.ImageLocation = imageRF;
                //PICTUREBOX
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Errore");
        }
    }
    // FINE STRINGA CHE PERMETTE ALLA COMBOBOX VIA DI DETERMINARE IL REFERENTE
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more context, like exception details, stacktrace?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm pretty new on c # (I've always worked on Access before). The error appears in the window (messagebox) and does not block the exe. Can I somehow get it from VS?

Comment: Yeah, remove the try/catch block. The try/catch block catches the exception and shows it in the messagebox. As you can see in the catch. If you remove that, it will show exactly where the error occurs

Comment: All the calls to `(string)dbr["..."]` are casting your objects to strings.  I'm willing to bet one of them is really a Byte.  Do you know what the types inside `dbr` really are?  Maybe one of the fields you are trying to pull out of it is really a Byte.  Or maybe ImageRF is actually a Byte array of the image, rather than a string to its location.

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg, this error: System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Messaggio=Impossibile eseguire il cast di oggetti di tipo 'System.Byte[]' sul tipo 'System.String'.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Only ImageRF is actually a byte array of the image, the rest are text values. In my DB ImageRF is set on IMAGE

Comment: @PaoloGogni Then the error line should be: `byte[] imageRF = (byte[])dbr["ImageRF"];`. But you might have another problem later when you try to set `imageRFPictureBox.ImageLocation`, because `imageRF` is not a location, but the bytes of the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So how could I get the picture? Actually I hadn't thought about this conversion thing. I tell you the truth, I was using, before "byte" to view the image via the path of the same in a folder. Everything ok but unfortunately sometimes the picture bothered me

Answer (score 0):

@SeanSkelly thanks! Thanks to your advice maybe I found the solution!

```
byte[] imageRF = (byte[])dbr["ImageRF"];
if (imageRF == null)
                {
                    imageRFPictureBox.Image = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imageRF);

                    imageRFPictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Errore");
        }
```